# Would several withdrawals (W) affect my chances at graduate school admission

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, grades, health

I am an undergraduate math major and I have already had to drop two classes (one due to my mother being sick and other to do with an attendance policy). This semester I'm having trouble with my health and concentrating and debating on dropping two more classes. My GPA is a good 3.9 but if I stay with these classes I am risking a lower GPA (as I am only an upper freshman with 26 credits). I am getting A's in my two other classes. My questions are:

*1. How bad are 4 W grades on a transcript when applying for a graduate program in mathematics?*

*2. Does having documentation saying I dropped due to depression/PTSD help if they can be "attached" to the transcript?*

*3. If I was able to do well in my GRE would that help soften the blow of a W grade?*

Thanks. I appreciate any answers. I have only two days to drop with a letter grade W.

P.S. I am at City University of New York if that makes a difference and plan on going to grad school there too. I realize that my question is similar to [How do some Ws on transcripts affect PhD admissions in mathematics?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29494) but it does not address GRE scores playing a role and whether documentation helps?

Comment: I had a number of W's. No one's ever asked about them ever: mathematics grad school admission at the same institution, job interviews, social interactions, ever.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me around how many Ws you had and where you applied? BTW it's completely ok if you don't feel like answering that question. I realize it could be difficult online. Nonetheless thanks.

Comment: I had about 4, maybe -- I tended to register for about 7 classes each semester and drop my least-favorite. This was at a state university.

Comment: FWIW, I disagree that this question is a duplicate of the other one, which asked about four W's in the freshman year. This asks about four Ws, three of which are due to "illness." Unless you make the case that "illness" is as "localized" as "freshman."